# how to find from where a function has been called (function call stack)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, javascript-debugger

I have a function which is being called from several files. Is there a way to determine from which file a function is being invoked by tools like Chrome DevTools?

```
function turnCoffeIntoCode (args) {
    // logic here
    debugger;
}
```

With the above, I can see the arguments being passed to the functions thanks to Chrome's developer tools but I cannot find from where the function is being called.

Comment: When debugger is paused, check out the function call stack.

Comment: Thanks for this! would you like to answer my question since I could not find my answer and question on stack overflow?

Comment: Instead of `debugger`, try `try { throw new Error('dummy'); } catch(ex) { console.log(ex.stacktrace) }`

Comment: Yes, Abhishek is right. You can check using call stack by selecting sources from DevTools or you can use console.trace(). For more details use this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace

Comment: @MatthewBarbara _Amr Elgarhy_ has answered already. You can accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the full call stack on the Chrome Developer Tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#call-stack

Just add a break point or a debugger; and you will be able to see the call stack and will be able to click and go to different functions in the stack.

And to read more, you can find many [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=call%20stack%20chrome) about the call stack in chrome.